# The equivalent of Python getattr, but for index or key

Tags: python, python-3.x

If a complex container A contains some element xyz, which can be accessed by key or by index (similar to lists or dictionaries):

```
xyz = A[somekey]
xyz = A[someindex]
```

how would I access the element, given a string? Basically I'd like the equivalent of:

```
method_of_a = getattr(A, 'method_of_a') # gets A.method_of_a
prop_of_a   = getattr(A, 'prop_of_a')   # gets A.prop_of_a
```

but I don't know of anything like:

```
element_by_key = getitem(A, 'somekey')# get A['somekey']
element_by_index = getitem(A,'2')# get A[2]
```

The reason I want that, is that I should copy a property or an element.
The problem is that I can only access the base containers, and a string representation of where to look. A more realistic exaple would be:

```
# copy A.some.weird.path[0].including['Keys']
#   to B.some.weird.path[0].including['Keys']
prop = magic_get_function(A, "some.weird.path[0].including['Keys']")
magic_set_function(B, "some.weird.path[0].including['Keys']", prop)
```

I'd very much like to not resort to eval, as eval is evil (or rather it's vulnerable).

If there's no other way than eval, how would you go at it?

Comment: Where does the string come from? It’s hard to answer the question without knowing which format it’s in. (If it always looks like `[the key]`, you can strip the brackets away with just `s[1:-1]`, for example, as in `s = "[xyz]"; A[s[1:-1]]`)

Comment: That's not how this works. When you do `A[b]`, there is no string "b" at work. In your case, the string "xyz" is not communicated to the class `A`, instead, the value behind the variable `xyz` is.

Comment: @Ry- I tried to make the question more understandeable. The string will always be the / a legal python call to get the element, but stripped of the base container.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? ``A['somekey']`` literally is "get item `'somekey'`. One of your examples interprets the second argument as itself (``getitem(A, 'somekey')`` -> ``A['somekey']``), the other interprets it as a name (``getitem(A, '2')`` -> ``A[2]``) - which one do you need? Are your keys always literals (``1``, ``0``, ``'foobar'``) or can they be names as well?

Comment: If `A` is a `dict`, you can simply use `A.get('some_key')`, if I get the question right

Comment: For some extra functionality, see the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html), in particular the `attrgetter` and `itemgetter`. But go with `somedict.get(key)` first.

Comment: Is the source any Python (potential spaces, comments around `.`, `[`, `]`, maybe expressions like `.path[1 + 1]`…), a specific subset of Python, whatever subset of Python you choose, or something that looks like Python much of the time but really isn’t (e.g. JavaScript)? (For full Python syntax, I’d start with [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse), but if the language is restricted enough then you can get away with simpler, faster, and more comfortable solutions.)